# Pytest - ModuleNotFoundError Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Soy muy bueno en esto de Python + selenium y la verdad estoy teniendo problemas con algo que al parecer es básico, pero no doy con la solución :( Si me pudieran ayudar por favor, se los agradecería enormemente.

La estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando quiero hacer el siguiente comando en el TERMINAL de Pycharm: pytest SetDePruebas_PlanAPV.py

Se da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado varias cosas como crear los archivos **init**.py (antes no los tenía, o también probe a renombrar los archivos sin los guiones bajos). No se por donde va el problema, si me pudieran ayudar plis :(

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

El IDE PyCharm organiza los proyectos en una jerarquía de archivos y carpetas, donde la raíz es la fuente principal inicial, de esta manera se crea el modelo de **project PyCharm**.
Los project PyCharm son un conjunto de archivos y carpetas con configuración de acceso que estandariza el desarrollo.

El mensaje que recibiste `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Variables` es un indicativo de que no se creó de acuerdo con el modelo de `project PyCharm`, sino que intentaste crear un proyecto siguiendo otro camino de desarrollo estándar y PyCharm no reconoció esa jerarquía de proyecto.

Para corregir y asegurarte de que tu proyecto se ejecute correctamente, haz clic con el botón derecho del mouse y busca `Mark Directory as` y selecciona la opción `Sources Root`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Marca la carpeta como* **Sources Root**, i*ndicando que es la carpeta principal del proyecto donde se encuentra el código que se utilizará*.

*El* **Sources Root** *es la carpeta de origen del proyecto cuando está marcada como sources root, es la carpeta principal.*

*Los* **Excluded roots** *son archivos y carpetas ignorados en la indexación.*

> En tu caso, simplemente marca la carpeta como sources root para
> resolver el problema de PyCharm de no encontrar el module Variables.

- [**jetbrains.com/help**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html#remove)